# How to get the pseudo inverse of a huge diagonal matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

If I have a diagonal matrix with diagonal 100Kx1 and how can I to get its pseudo inverse?
I won't be able to diagonalise the matrix and then get the inverse like I would do for small matrix so this won't work

np.linalg.pinv(np.diag(D))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the reciprocals of the nonzero elements. You can check with a smaller diagonal matrix that this is what `pinv` does.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have a vector of 100K x 1 named as A:

```
A = np.arange(100000) # will create a vector of 100k x 1
diagnoal_matrix = np.diag(A)
```

Then, you can find pseudo inverse of diagonal matrix as following:

```
np.linalg.pinv(diagnoal_matrix)
```

Sample code will look like:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(100000)
diagnoal_matrix = np.diag(A)
B = np.linalg.pinv(diagnoal_matrix)
print B
```

It will print the output as following:

```
   [[    0     0     0 ...,     0     0     0]
 [    0     1     0 ...,     0     0     0]
 [    0     0     2 ...,     0     0     0]
 ..., 
 [    0     0     0 ..., 99997     0     0]
 [    0     0     0 ...,     0 99998     0]
 [    0     0     0 ...,     0     0 99999]]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I dont want to get pseudo inverse of a random matrix I want to get the inverse of my own diagonal matrix

Comment: Then pass your diagonal matrix to np.linalg.pinv() as np.linalg.pinv(diag_matrix)

Comment: I can't I only have the diagonal saved and its huge I cant create a diagonal matrix and then gets its inverse

Comment: Pass your diagonal vector to np.diag(diag) and diag = np.array([1,2,3,4]). It is the list of diagonal you have!

Comment: I can't its huge! it 100K I wrote this in the question